# How to develop NavigationController in Xcode 4.2 without using storyboard and and tableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I am learning Xcode and working for IOS developer as trainee. I am using Xcode 4.2 and Lion OS. My targeted OS will be ios 3+ version. Somebody told me that using storyboard gives the problem for older version. So i want to develop without using Storyboard for navigationController. Help me out, cause all the old tutorials does not help at all, cause there are lots of missmatch due to change in xcode version.
Help me please.

Answer (score 3):

For creating a navigation controller, select a Single View Application for your project template. In the AppDelegate.h, create an instance of the UINavigationController. In the AppDelegate.m file, do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This will give the base as a navigation controller. You can add other views on this using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

While you creating new project

there is check marks for use storyboard just remove it from there.then move ahead as you are moving before. [image]

Comment: haha, that was not my question @Neel ...but thanks... my question is, all the tutorials are based on older version of xcode, and I am not able to follow it, such as there is no App Delegate in xib file, no window based application during creating new project as window based application has app delegate.h and .m file including mainwindow.xib....and lots of other things.....could you please just show me how to make two pages app having navigation but without use of table...just simple two page....thanks

Comment: then there is simple one line solution for this return add below line in your main filr and follow the answer of Invincible. UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: if you need any more help then ask here

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AppDelegate, and play around with them. See what happens and you will learn.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>{


}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
//*****************************************//

.m file

 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[Categories alloc] initWithNibName:@"Categories" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[Coupons alloc] initWithNibName:@"Coupons" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[Favourites alloc] initWithNibName:@"Favourites" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[AroundMe alloc] initWithNibName:@"AroundMe" bundle:nil];

    viewController2.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Coupons", @"Coupons");
    viewController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coupons.png"];
    viewController3.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Favourites", @"Favourites");
    viewController3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favourites.png"];


   // UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
    UINavigationController *navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1,navController2, navController3, navController4, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```